# After server transfer some commands wont work

Tags: magento2, cli, transfer

Hello yesterday i transfered my store to new server (Ubuntu 18).
After clean installion of Magento i want to run via cli command for the backup but i takes this message 
 `-bash: bin/magento: Permission denied`

Any suggest?

Comment: from root of your magento project, run this command `sudo chmod -R 0777 bin`

Comment: i get this now Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will b e suppressed on further calls in /var/www/vhosts/store/httpdocs/vendor/co linmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

Comment: well my php in cli set 7.2 in setting i have 7.0 prntscr.com/kv0aw5 prntscr.com/kv0b5c

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above suggests, it sounds like the permissions aren't set correctly or the ownership is wrong.

To make sure the files are owned by the correct user, `cd` into the magento root directory and run `chown youruser:youruser . -R`

For file and directory permissions, from the magento root directory you can run the following;

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento`

Comment: worked!!! but i get this now Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will b                 e suppressed on further calls in /var/www/vhosts/store/httpdocs/vendor/co                 linmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

Comment: well my php in cli set 7.2 in setting i have 7.0 http://prntscr.com/kv0aw5 http://prntscr.com/kv0b5c

Comment: btw after this find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento blank page i got frontend and backend too

Comment: @darkattack if this worked can you accept the answer? Also if you're having a whitescreen - try running `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` to get better error reporting on the frontend.